# A one-to-one function from a finite set to itself is onto - how to prove by induction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I'm not sure if I can do this without knowing what f actually is?

> Let $X$ be a finite set with $n$ elements and $f: X \rightarrow X$ a one-to-one function. Prove by induction that $f$ is an onto function.

Any pointers? I don't even know how to make a base case for this.

Comment: THe base case is pretty pretty much always with $n=1$.  In this case $X$ would be a finite set with 1 element.

Comment: From there, Let X is a finite set with k elements and f:X->X a one to one function and assume that f is an onto function.  What does that mean?  Apply that assumption to the set with n+1 elements...

Comment: Hm..I wonder if I can actually use Pidgeon Hole for this...thanks for the help getting started Christopher!

Comment: no pigeonhole here.  You have to use definitions of 1-1 and onto functions.  Pigeonhole implies a counting problem.  This is not a counting problem.  This is an induction argument using known definitions.  You anchor your base case and you make an assumption on k and then try to show it holds for k+1 effectively causing a "chain reaction" proof on all values that n can take on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Induct on $|X|$. The base case $|X|=1$ is obvious since then there is only one function $X\rightarrow X$.

Now, suppose inductively that $|E|\leq n$ implies that every injective $E\rightarrow E$ is surjective. Suppose $|X|=n+1$ and let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be injective. Seeking a contradiction, suppose $f$ is not surjective so $|f(X)|\leq n$. Then $g:f(X)\rightarrow f(X)$ given by $g(t)=f(t)$ is injective and the inductive hypothesis implies $g$ is surjective. That is, $g(f(X))=f(X)$ so for every $y\in X$ there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(f(x))=f(y)\Rightarrow f(x)=y$. Thus $f$ is surjective, a contradiction. Hence $f$ is surjective and this closes the induction.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The $E$ threw me off for a second, but I read through a few times and that cleared it up.

Comment: Of course the base case $|X|=0$ would be "even more obvious". ;)

Comment: I altered the proof to make it a bit nicer. Hagen--I agree!

Comment: The last line is kind of hard to understand, you get a contradiction because $f$ is surjective therefore $f$ is surjective...

Comment: Is this true for infinite set also?

Comment: @shinzou He never assumed $f$ is surjective. The condition $f(f(X))=f(X)$ means that $f\circ f$ hits everything in the image of $f$. Choose an arbitrary domain element $y\in X$. Then $f\circ f$ has to hit $f(y)$. In other words, there exists $x\in X$ with $f(f(x))=f(y)$. The fact that f is injective then requires $f(x)=y$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, non-inductive approach. Makes use of the definition of Dedekind-infinite/finite.

Suppose we have injective (1-1) function $f: X\rightarrow X$

Using proof by contrapositive, suppose that $f$ is *not* surjective (onto).

Let $X'=f(X)$. Show $X'$ is a proper subset of $X$.

Construct $f': X'\rightarrow X$, the inverse of $f$ on $X'$.

Show $f'$ is both injective and surjective. By definition, $X$ would then be infinite.

Taking the contrapositive, if $X$ is finite then $f$ is surjective (onto).