# Why is ( Injections,∘ ) not a group but (Injections_finite, ∘) one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

As the title says, I struggle to understand why ( Injections,∘ ) is not a group while ( Injections_finite,∘ ) is.

As I understand, there are 4 properties needed for set to be a group.

- Associativity
- Closed operation
- Inverses
- Identity

***Closed operation***

For both statements, this is valid. Since these are functions, they are defined on the entire domain.

***Identity***

The identity function which takes every element to itself is the identity : f(*x*) -> *x*

***Associativity***

It is verifiable as a result of closure.

***Inverses***

This is what I have issues understanding.

- **For ( Injections,∘ ), the explanation given is**: Since the domain can have
  infinite size, it is not necessary that these functions are invertible.

My question:

- What does the infinite size of the domain have to do with the absence of inverse for functions that are part of that domain?

---

- **For ( Injections_infinite,∘ ), the explanation given is**: The existence of inverses is the result of the proposition which states that if the domain and co-domain are finite and have the same size, every injective function from one to the other is also a bijection. Since these are bijections, their invertability follows.

My question:

- Does "injective function from one to the other is also a bijection" mean that functions that are mapped from a finite domain to a finite co-domain are both injective and surjective?
- Why does their bijection imply invertability?

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: I assume you are talking about functions from a set $S$ to itself?  If so, then...yes.  If $S$ is finite then injective implies surjective (by the pigeon hole principle).  This is clearly false if $S$ is infinite.  For a reference (in the finite case) see, e.g., [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366146/a-one-to-one-function-from-a-finite-set-to-itself-is-onto-how-to-prove-by-indu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like lulu in the comments, I'm also assuming you're talking about functions that map a set $A$ to itself since otherwise injectivity does not necessarily imply surjectivity if $A$ is finite (take $f : \{1,2\} \to \{1,2,3\}$ defined by $f(x) = x$).

Anyway, your questions:

> What does the infinite size of the domain have to do with the absence of inverse for functions that are part of that domain?

I think the best way to answer this is to exhibit an injective function $f : A \to A$ where $A$ is infinite and $f$ is not surjective.  Then since $f$ is not surjective, it's not bijective, which means it doesn't have an inverse.  Take $A = \Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3, \dots\}$ and take $f : A \to A$ to be $f(x) = x + 1$.  Then $f$ is clearly injective, but it is not surjective because there is no $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

> Does "injective function from one to the other is also a bijection" mean that functions that are mapped from a finite domain to a finite co-domain are both injective and surjective?

No.  It means if you have a function $f : A \to A$ that you *already know to be injective*, and if $A$ is finite, **then** you can conclude that $f$ is bijective (i.e., $f$ is also surjective).  (See the link lulu provided in the comment on your post for details on that.)  But it's possible to have a function $g : B \to B$ where $B$ is finite and $g$ is neither surjective nor injective, e.g., take $B = \{1,2,3\}$ and $g(1) = g(2) = g(3) = 1$.

> Why does their bijection imply invertability?

Because if $f : A \to A$ is bijective, then (even if $A$ is infinite) for every $b \in A$ there is a **unique** $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b.$  Therefore the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is simply the function that sends $b$ "back" to $a$.  That is, if $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$, then $f^{-1}(b) = a$.  And this function is well defined because $f$ is surjective (so we know that $f^{-1}(b)$ actually has a value) and $f$ is injective (so we know that $a$ is the only element in $A$ such that $f^{-1}(b) = a$)

Comment: So bijectivity is a requirement for the existance of an inverse?

Comment: @Pete, for the existence of an inverse function, yes.  But even without bijectivity it's still possible to talk about "inverse elements" for specific values.  For example, $f(x) = x^3 - 9x$ is not bijective because it's not injective, but we can still say, for example, $f^{-1}(80) = 5$.  But we can't say, for example, $f^{-1}(0)$, because there are three values of $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.  But I think this "inverse element" concept may really be more of a precalculus/college algebra thing since I haven't seen it anywhere but there.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the infinite size of the domain have to do with the absence of inverse   for functions that are part of that domain?

Because if $S$ is **finite** and $f:S\to S$ is injective, then it has an inverse. However, if $S$ is not finite, then it may not have an inverse. For example, $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ defined as $f(n)=2n$ is **not** invertible.

> Does "injective function from one to the other is also a bijection" mean that functions that are mapped from a finite domain to a finite co-domain are both injective and surjective?

No, it only means that functions that are mapped from a finite domain to a finite co-domain **of the same cardinality** that are *injective* are also surjective.

> Why does their bijection imply invertability?

Because bijection always implies invertibility.

Comment: Wouldn't the invert of f(_n_) = 2_n_ be f^-1(_n_) = 0.5_x_

Comment: @Pete No, because that function is **not** a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ (because $f(3)$ is not an integer)