# If $f$ has no non trivial fixed points and $f\circ f$ is the identity then $f(x)=x^{-1}$ and $G$ is abelian for $f$ an automorphism of $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group, involutions

> Let $f$ be an automorphism of the finite group $G$ such that $f\circ f=id$ and $f(x)=x\implies x=e$
>
> Prove that $f(x)=x^{-1}~\forall x\in G$

If we can prove that $f(x)$ and $x$ commute for any given $x\in G$ then we're done with the proof because it would imply

$$xf(x)=f(x)x$$

$$f(f(x))f(x)=f(x)x$$

Because $f\circ f=id$. And since $f$ is a homomorphism:
$$f(f(x)x)=f(x)x\implies f(x)x=e\implies f(x)=x^{-1}$$

I don't know how to proceed

The fact that $G$ is abelian can be deduced once we have $f(x)=x^{-1}$ because that function is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian

Comment: see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Fixed-point-free_involution_on_finite_group_is_inverse_map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Exercise:** Let $G$ be a finite group , $f$ an automorphism of $G$ with $f(x) =x \iff x=e$. Prove that every $g \in G$ can be written as $$g=x^{-1}f(x)$$

Proof : Define $\alpha:G \to G$ by $\alpha(x)=x^{-1}f(x)$. Use the hypothesis to prove $\alpha$ is one one. That is,  $$\alpha(x)=\alpha(y) \Longrightarrow x^{-1}f(x)=y^{-1}f(y)$$ $$\hspace{2cm}\Longrightarrow yx^{-1}=f(yx^{-1})$$

$$\hspace{2.2cm}\Longrightarrow yx^{-1}=e\;\;\text{by hyp}$$

$$\Longrightarrow y=x$$

Finiteness implies $\alpha$ is onto as well. Onto means,  for every $g \in G$, there exist $x \in G$ such that $\alpha(x)=x^{-1}f(x)=g$ $\;\blacksquare$

---

Proof of your result: $$f(g)=f\Big(x^{-1}f(x)\Big)=f(x^{-1})f^2(x)=f(x^{-1})x=\Big[x^{-1}f(x)\Big]^{-1}=g^{-1}$$

Comment: another correction in the statement of the exercise: $f(x) =x \iff x=e$

Comment: Thanks! .......

Comment: Why does the finiteness of $G$ imply that $\alpha$ is onto?

Comment: A one one map from a finite set to itself is onto as well. see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366146/a-one-to-one-function-from-a-finite-set-to-itself-is-onto-how-to-prove-by-indu

Comment: Yeah I mean onto is a property of being 1 to 1. But here we have to prove the 1 to 1 property by showing that it's both into and onto, so why is it onto? (without using that it's 1 to 1, because that's what we are trying to prove)

Comment: Onto is surjective right? Because that's what I have a problem with

Comment: Yes! I mean surjective.

Comment: Ah ok I get it! Injective + finite $\implies$ surjective

Comment: Yes! exactly!...